# Shadowrun 3rd edition ruthenium polymer

Tags: equipment, shadowrun

What book and page describes ruthenium polymer? I have Shadowrun 3rd Edition books and I believe that is what it was called in 3rd edition. It's a camo suit that functions by displaying a live image of what is behind the wearer, effectively cloaking them.

Comment: Huh, my research group is working on some ruthenium compounds and some metal polymers, but sadly not a real-world ruthenium polymer I can point out.

Answer (score 5):

Man & Machine, page 114.

Ruthenium polymer is also located in 1st edition Shadowtech, page 94, and 4th edition Arsenal, page 50.

It is listed in 2nd edition Fields of Fire, page 105, in a list that has been compiled (at least partially) from items in 1st edition Shadowtech, so I presume the item is intended to have remained identical. I have no way of guaranteeing this, however.